# Get sum of a batch of model.evaluate results in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

In a sentence, I have several customized evaluation metrics, a large set of evaluation data that have to run in batches during evaluation, and I want to get the sum of these metrics of all evaluation batches.

More details:

I build a model using TensorFlow's Estimator class, and it works fine for training and evaluation. The problem is, my evaluation data is too big and I need to split them into batches using a customized `input_fn`.

The call looks like

```
eval_res = model.evaluate(input_fn=lambda:eval_input_fn(params['eval_data'], params['batch_size']))
```

In this case, I'll get the evaluation metric dict (let's call it `eval_dict`) output every step through the terminal output, but `eval_res` only has the result of the last evaluation batch.

Let's assume `eval_res` actually contains a list of `eval_dict`, then what I want is the sum across all the elements in `eval_res` that has the same key.

An example is like

```
eval_dict = {'metric1': 0.0, 'metric2': 0.0}

eval_list = [{'metric1': 0.1, 'metric2': 0.0}, {'metric1': 0.5, 'metric2': 1.0}]

desired_eval_result = {'metric1': 0.6, 'metric2': 1.0}
```

I tried to store the metric ops into a graph collection using `tf.add_to_collection`, and then use `tf.get_collection` to get them. But the result of `tf.get_collection` is always empty. I suppose I need to specify the graph name to it but I'm not sure how to find the graph of an Estimator class.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand the question. Do you just need to sum the dictionaries in regular Python after calling model.evaluate multiple times, or are you trying to do something like tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_mean across multiple evaluation steps (where the input is queue-based)?

Comment: I think it is more like `streaming_mean` because I just call model.evaluate once and the input is a queue. If I use streaming_mean, will the mean be reset for each model.evaluate call or not?

Answer (score 1):

Every time `model.evaluate` get called, it will run the `model_fn` again. So if I create several variables using `tf.Variable` and update the metric score of each evaluation batch to a variable using `assign_add`, then I can successfully get the accumulated metric score for all evaluation batches.

And because every time `model_fn` get called, the variables get reset to 0 by the `tf.Variable(0., dtype=tf.float32)` call, previous evaluation will not affect the result of next evaluation.

A code sample looks like:

```
hr_mean_rank_var = tf.Variable(0, name="hr_mean_rank", dtype=tf.float32, trainable=False)
hr_mr_update = hr_mean_rank_var.assign_add(mean_rank_eval_op)
eval_metric_dict = {'hr_mr' : hr_mr_update}
```

This time when I call

```
eval_res = model.evaluate(input_fn=lambda:eval_input_fn(params['eval_data'], params['batch_size']))
```

I'll get the accumulated metric scores.